# Looking for correct way to populate view model one location permission is granted

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I have a fairly standard location manager service controlling a mapview - which displays when the app loads. I also have View Model that contains map annotations restricted to the current region of the map (they are conditionally loaded from FireStore using GeoFire).

Both location manager and view model are injected into the environement in map entry point as follows:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(LocationManager())
            .environmentObject(VenuesViewModel())
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to trigger the view model to update/populate when after location permission is given, otherwise it is empty on first use until the user either switch view (in which case the function to get annotations is called in `onAppear`) or on a button tap, but not after the current location becomes available to the app.

I tried calling the update function within `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` but I  get an error 'Precision must be less than 23'.

Any tips for the right time and place to call the function to update the view model much apprecaited.

Comment: In your `App`, you could try declaring: `@StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()`,
 then add an `.onAppear {...}` where you call the appropriate functions. Also use
 `.environmentObject(locationManager)` etc... to pass the models to `ContentView`.

Comment: Architecture wise a “Manager” shouldn’t be in the View environment. It should be in the ViewModel as a variable, you can then use Combine’s publishers to get updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is SwiftUI you should have one `View` struct to request permission and `if` permission is granted then show the next `View` struct. Each `View` struct can have its own location manager there is no need to reuse the same one for different actions. In SwiftUI you should "the View structs should be the primary encapsulation mechanism", i.e. not objects. See:

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040

Especially 20:53

To fetch annotations use `.task(id: mapCoordinate)` and store the result in an `@State`. This way the task will be cancelled and restarted if the coordinate changes.

Comment: Been thinking about this comment. It makes sense for my app to open on the map view, but I could have 2 - on that it shown initially and one that is shown when permission is granted. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It depends what you want to do when authorised, eg if you wanted to show buttons then you could have an overlay on the Map and check if authorised in the overlayed View's body. You could also run a task to fetch your annotations. Usually you will have to show some UI telling the user to visit settings to re-authorise.